# Set text of clicked ListView item as variable

Tags: java, android, listview

I have successfully populated a ListView with an `onItemClickListener` that takes the user to a new Activity when clicked.

But I'd like to pass on the name of the ListView item that was clicked as a variable (so I can use it in an SQLite query).

I understand that I need to pass this variable as an extra in an Intent, but how can I capture that variable in the first place?

Here's my current code:

```
authorsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           // String author = captured ListView item                    
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 authorsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
       String author = authorsListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();                 
  }
 });
```

Comment: This was the answer that worked for me, except I replaced the `position` variable with `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The list you are passing in the adapter, get the reference of that and get the object of the list using get method/ and use 'i' variable as an argument for get method. It will return the object of click position. And done. Use this object get the require property and pass that with intent to new activity.